# How to group datetime column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to divide my datetime column data into 4 groups named as: 12AM-06 AM,06 AM-12PM,12PM-18PM,18PM-12AM
. How can I do that?

```
          Time_Interval
0         00:00:00
1         00:00:00
2         06:00:00
3         12:00:00
4         12:00:00
            ...   
209526    18:00:00
209527    00:00:00
209528    06:00:00
209529    12:00:00
209530    12:00:00
```

At first I tried to convert datetime to object but got this error : Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values And here is my code:

```
df['Time_Interval'] = df['Time_Interval'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

What is the best solution for this?

Comment: Hmm, are you sure this column isn't already a string column? Not sure why you'd be getting that error if the column is datetime...

Comment: But after doing that you should be able to just write a function that assigns categories based on string comparisons.

Comment: What do these groups contain? What does your expected output look like?

Comment: I expect something like change 06:00:00 to 6 am-12 pm and my data is datetime type.